# Android muticolumn listview with headinng

Tags: android

How can we give the heading for muticolumn list view (Like table heading)

For example I need like this

```
RouteCode   RouteName   Outelet
 0001        aaaaa        10
 0002        bbbbb        20
```

But currently display like this

```
      0001        aaaaa        10
      0002        bbbbb        20
```

I have done using `SimpleAdapter`

```
  ListView list = getListView();
    sd = new SimpleAdapter(this, routhPath, R.layout.route_path,new String[] {"routeCode","routeName","outlets" },new int[] { R.id.routeCode,R.id.routeName,R.id.outlets});
    list.setAdapter(sd);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    list.setSelected(true);
    list.setSelection(0);
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    list.setItemChecked(positions, true);
    list.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
```

My list view also :

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
              android:clickable="true"
              android:dividerHeight="2dp" 
              android:divider="@drawable/divider"
              android:textFilterEnabled="true"
              android:scrollbars="vertical"
              android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
              android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
              android:clipChildren="true" 
              android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
              android:smoothScrollbar="true"
              android:cacheColorHint="#fff"
              android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
                />
```

**Another question**

How to differentiate particular row in the list (differentiate mean different color)? I need this for default route is set in db. then that row should be show with different color.
How can i implement this.?

**for example when it load i want to show 2nd or 3rd or.. row in red color ..**
Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**First question**

Do you want a header for a couple of items in the list or just a header for the complete list?

If you just want a header for the list you can use [listview.addHeaderView(View v)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) Or the other addHeaderView, check the link for the two.

Another way of doing it would be to use a custom adapter if you want different headers in the list. Either do your own adapter, there is plenty of different examples out there for custom adapters.

There is also different libraries out there. Two examples for having different headers within the listview is first [seperatedlistadapter](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) and another one is [CommonsWare MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge).

Edit: **Your second question**
I would definitely use my own custom adapter for doing this. One great example is here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html
In that example they have different drawables for different rows.

```
        // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
        holder.text.setText(DATA[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap((position & 1) == 1 ? mIcon1 : mIcon2);
```

Depending on what position is required the image alternates.

Comment: I don't understand send question's answer.How we can do. please guide me

Comment: I am really sorry . 2nd question .. I don't understand 2nd question's answer.How we can do. please guide me – Nagkeeran Piraba 26 mins ago

Comment: Well, take a look on the link in the second answer. There you have a custom adapter for your listview. The adapter gives the view to the listview which takes it and shows it. Its just that you need to decide what to show in the getView function. I can not really learn you things about the adapters, as I said there are TONS and TONS of examples on just adapters out there. Take a look here http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b7d2b7c275ac730f/beedcdfba16bc007?pli=1 for example.

Answer (score 1):

I have done first question like this :

```
 View row = null;
 ListView list = getListView();
    sd = new SimpleAdapter(this, routhPath, R.layout.route_path,new String[] {"routeCode","routeName","outlets" },new int[] { R.id.routeCode,R.id.routeName,R.id.outlets});
    row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.route_path_row, null, false);
    getListView().addHeaderView(row);
```

I have created 2 xml for list contents .one is header another one is row.